# Find POCO with MongoDB .Net driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

MongoDB was harder than I remembered! I've tried various versions of if-exists-replace-else-insert with various functions and options. It should be easy, shouldn't it?

It's my personal opinion that the following should work.

```
var collection = storageClient.GetCollection<Observer>("observers");
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Observer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.MyId), new CreateIndexOptions { Unique = true });

foreach (var observer in _observers)
{
     observer.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

     var res = await collection.FindAsync(o => o.MyId == observer.MyId);
     if (res==null ||res.Current == null) {
         await collection.InsertOneAsync(observer); //Part 1, fails 2nd time solved with res.MoveNextAsync()
     } 
     else
     {
            observer.ID = res.Current.Single().ID;
            var res2 = await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(o=>o.MyId==observer.MyId, observer);

            var res3 = await collection.FindAsync(o => o.MyId == observer.MyId);
            await res3.MoveNextAsync();
            Debug.Assert(res3.Current.Single().Timestamp == observer.Timestamp); //Part 2, Assert fails.
     }
}
```

Observer looks approximately like this:

```
public class Observer : IObserver
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public int MyId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The second time I run this with the exact same collection I unexpectedly get:

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: db.observers.$MyId_1  dup key: { : 14040 }
```

Edit:

Added original part two code: replacement.

Edit 2:

Now my code looks like this. Still fails.

```
var collection = storageClient.GetCollection<Observer>("gavagai_mentions");
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Observer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.MyID), new CreateIndexOptions { Unique = true });
    foreach (var observer in _observers)
    {
    observer.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    // Create a BsonDocument version of the POCO that we can manipulate
    // and then remove the _id field so it can be used in a $set.
    var bsonObserver = observer.ToBsonDocument();
    bsonObserver.Remove("_id");

    // Create an update object that sets all fields on an insert, and everthing
    // but the immutable _id on an update.
    var update = new BsonDocument("$set", bsonObserver);
    update.Add(new BsonDocument("$setOnInsert", new BsonDocument("_id", observer.ID)));

    // Enable the upsert option to create the doc if it's not found.
    var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };
    var res = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(o => o.MyID == observer.MyID,
                          update, options);


    var res2 = await collection.FindAsync(o => o.MyID == observer.MyID);
    await res2.MoveNextAsync();
    Debug.Assert(res2.Current.Single().Timestamp == observer.Timestamp); //Assert fails, but only because MongoDB stores dates as UTC, or so I deduce. It works!!
    }
```

Comment: For future readers, the docs are here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/#finding-documents

Comment: Thanks Craig! That's actually helpful. It's frustratingly difficult to get help on StackOverflow these days. Please check out part two if you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586064/replace-poco-with-mongodb-net-driver-2

Comment: What you're looking to do should be able to be accomplished via a [`UpdateOneAsync`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_UpdateOneAsync.htm?_ga=1.73733265.2070706799.1441907109) with the upsert option to create the doc if it's not found. That way you could do this atomically. Have you looked at that? You'd structure it as a `$set` of all fields so that it would effectively replace the doc, if found.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, honestly, YES! ;) The documentation is not copy/paste however, since I'me using POCOs. I get various errors about not being able to update _id if I have one, others if not. I implore you to set me straight as I feel like a complete moron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this atomically with [`UpdateOneAsync`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_UpdateOneAsync.htm?_ga=1.81689620.2070706799.1441907109) by using the `IsUpsert` option to create the doc if it doesn't already exist.

```cs
foreach (var observer in _observers)
{
    // Create a BsonDocument version of the POCO that we can manipulate
    // and then remove the _id field so it can be used in a $set.
    var bsonObserver = observer.ToBsonDocument();
    bsonObserver.Remove("_id");

    // Create an update object that sets all fields on an insert, and everthing
    // but the immutable _id on an update.
    var update = new BsonDocument("$set", bsonObserver);
    update.Add(new BsonDocument("$setOnInsert", new BsonDocument("_id", observer.ID)));

    // Enable the upsert option to create the doc if it's not found.
    var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };    
    var res = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(o => o.MyId == observer.MyId,
                                              update, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @JohnnyHK. However:  Invalid modifier specified $setOnInsert

Comment: [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert) was introduced in 2.4; what version is your server?

Comment: Apparantly older. I upgraded and it works... better. Assert still fails, see edit.

Comment: Ok, but that `Debug.Assert` wasn't in your question when I answered this. There are all sorts of potential issues with time stamps so that part's best asked as a new question.

Comment: Haha, that cracks me up (not your fault, @JohnnyHK). It IS part of a new question, one that was closed by over zealous reviewers for being a duplicate of this one. Hence the mess. I've edited in the timestamp part. And yes, I'm expecting the error to be ludicrously easy.

Comment: @Martin I think you're missing the point of my comment. Your original question was answered so you should mark it as answered and create a new question for just the timestamp part as that's a completely separate issue. Otherwise the questions and answers get unwieldy.

Comment: I'm confused too. My first issue was with Find. I've solved that. My second issue was Replace/Update the found document. Your take, for which I'm grateful, attempts to solve both issues in one swat. It's not solved because as far as I can see the document is neither updated nor replaced. I don't think I have a timestamp issue. If I do, I wouldn't know how to pose the question except posting the exact same code and asking, "Can anybody point out the timestamp issue?". Then being closed. Not trying to be obnoxious, I just can't solve this on my own. I'm blind after working on this too long.

Comment: @Martin The DateTime issue is likely an issue of resolution or time zone. If you look at the resulting doc you should see its value has changed, it's just not matching up exactly with the source time with the full .NET precision; thus the failed assert.

Comment: Yeees!! Thank you, I never meant to doubt you. Indeed, the Assert compares Utc kind to Local. This experience has been exacerbating but I picked up so many new pointers from just one question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's just been a long time since I worked with cursors.

```
await res.MoveNextAsync();
```

helped.

This stuff is not hard to Google, but the fact of the matter is, I failed, so I'm going to leave the question up.

If you have an answer for part two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586064/replace-poco-with-mongodb-net-driver-2, then and would really like to post it here then I'll be happy two edit the questions.

As was pointed out in the comments the information is in fact readily available in the docs http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/#finding-documents.

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are attempting to replace documents where the ID fields are different. ID fields in MongoDB are immutable and, as such, cannot be replaced. So, when you attempt to "replace" one document with another, the intended use is a replacement of the same document with the same identifier. In this particular case, it is entirely possible you'll end up trying to replace a document with one that already exists in the collection. Perhaps explaining the issue itself (what you're trying to do) in a different question and not referencing this one would be helpful).

Comment: What do you mean by "referencing this one"? The mess in this question which I'm not sure how I will be clean up after all issues are solved is due to the other question being closed as a duplicate of this one. They reference each other.